# How to visualize microservices REST API on HTML page?

Tags: python, html, rest, microservices, tornado

This is very general question and I don't expect a code answer (example would be nice), but a reference or subject for reading.

I have a python code for microservices REST API (using Tornado) and I want to make the UI more friendly.

for example, I got 3 files:

book.py:

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self):
        self.books = []

    def add_book(self, title, author):
        new_book = {}
        new_book["Title"] = title
        new_book["Author"] = author
        self.books.append(new_book)
        print("Book: {0}".format(new_book))
        return json.dumps(new_book)

    def get_all_books(self):
        return self.books

    def json_list(self):
        return json.dumps(self.books)
```

api.py:

```
books = Book()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Book Microservice v1")

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/v1", MainHandler),
        (r"/v1/addbook", AddHandler, dict(books = books)),
        (r"/v1/getbooks", GetHandler, dict(books = books)),
        ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

addhandler.py:

```
class AddHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self, books):
        self.books = books

    def get(self):
        title = self.get_argument('title')
        author = self.get_argument('author')
        result = self.books.add_book(title, author)
        self.write(result)
```

When I want to add a book I type:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/addbook?title="Harry Potter"&author="J.K Rowling"
```

To list all the books I type:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/addbook
```

How can I make it more friendly?
I mean that the user will enter the site an the press on "Add book" and will delivered to page with textboxes for name an author.
And a list of books instead of the current output :

```
[{"Title": "\"How to Make a Million Dollars Blogging\"", "Author": "\"Bill Ward\""}, {"Title": "\"Harry Potter\"", "Author": "\"J.K Rowling\""}]
```

*code from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/python-rest-api-example-part-1) by [Bill Ward](https://dzone.com/users/3356926/admintome.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems like what you are looking for here may be Templates.

Here is the [Tornado documentation on Templates](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/templates.html)

Let me know if this helps, or if there is anything else I can help